# Thread Output to Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, treeview

I'm making a python application in tkinter.  In the GUI, I have a treeview which lists all the threads which each have the same target function.  The target function prints output to the console, but I'd like to capture each thread's output, and instead have a text box below the treeview which displays the thread's output when the column in the treeview is clicked.  Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: There's a thousand ways to do that. I suppose the simplest is to have the thread set an attribute and when you click on the treeview element have tkinter retrieve the attribute for that thread.

Comment: Well in the target function, there are multiple print commands. I wasn't looking to just create a string variable for each thread and then have it written to the text box by clicking on the treeview.  I am looking for a way to reroute the print command to a log for each thread and then display the log in tkinter somehow.

Comment: Oh. Use a Queue. Each thread can `put` message into the queue and the tkinter GUI can read them on a regular basis.

Comment: Would there then be a way to get only entries from a specified thread?

Comment: You would need a Queue for each thread then, which really isn't a problem. Or have the thread include an identifier in whatever they put into the queue and filter it out on demand.